# how to draw a flag using ImageMagic

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to create flag image files from the command line that look something like this:
[image]

Having 5 or 4 rectangles arranged above/below each other, where each rectangle has a different color (hex or rgb)

I can use this command to generate a rectangle with a single solid color having the same dimensions of a flag:

```
convert -size 1800x900 xc:#990000 flag.png
```

[image]

But how can I align multiple different colors in say a list? Such as: `#c72b40,#e7919d,#0a8683,#e7919d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command will make a flag of simple horizontal stripes, evenly spaced...

```
convert xc:#36399A xc:#EF1897 xc:#FEDF12 xc:#FFFFFF xc:#A77BCA -append -scale 1800x900! +repage flag.png
```

That creates a single pixel of each color in the flag, appends them vertically, and scales the result to 1800x900.